# Dual pane does not work in Thunar?

Tags: nautilus, thunar

I have Thunar 1.6.3 but dual pane (comes up with F3 in nautilus) does not work. How do I enable it? I only have tabs!?

Running UbuntuStudio 14.04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installed [nemo [image: Install nemo]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nemo). Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Thunar doesn't have this functionality, sadly instead they opted for tabs, you can open a new tab with CTRL+T, you can also drag files on tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Umm ... what makes you think that Thunar has the option to show dual panes? It's a fairly basic file manager and has fewer features than some others: that's why it is favoured in lightweight Linux distros. If you want dual panes I suggest you install Nautilus.